# Which % of the global economy is considered "emerging"?

Tags: index-fund, emerging-markets

I have two funds in my portfolio: ***developed*** and ***emerging***. If I wanted to replicate an **All World** fund, such as *Vanguard Total World Stock Index Fund Investor Shares* (VTWSX), how should I allocate my money between the developed and emerging funds?

Or, rephrasing the question: Which % of the global economy is considered "emerging"? Which % of the global economy is considered "developed"?

I thought about calculating it myself, but I couldn't help feeling that there should be a clear, concise answer somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The company that runs the fund (Vanguard) on their [website](https://personal.vanguard.com/us/funds/snapshot?FundId=0628&FundIntExt=INT#tab=2) has the information on the general breakdown of their investments of that fund. They tell you that as of July 31st 2016 it is 8.7% emerging markets. They even specifically list the 7000+ companies they have purchased stocks in.

Of course the actual investment and percentages could [change every day].

> Vanguard may publish on this Site, in the fund's holdings on the
>   webpages, a detailed list of the securities (aggregated by issuer for
>   money market funds) held in a Vanguard fund (portfolio holdings) as of
>   the most recent calendar-quarter-end, 30 days after the end of the
>   calendar quarter, except for Vanguard Market Neutral Fund (60 calendar
>   days after the end of the calendar quarter), Vanguard index funds (15
>   calendar days after the end of the month), and Vanguard Money Market
>   Funds (within five [5] business days after the last business day of
>   the preceding month). Except with respect to Vanguard Money Market
>   Funds, Vanguard may exclude any portion of these portfolio holdings
>   from publication on this Site when deemed in the best interest of the
>   fund.

Comment: Thank you. The spot on, swift answer I was looking for. I was shocked at first, seeing how there is no exact correspondence between country GDP over world GDP and country stock market presence over world stock market.